# How do I get the children of a specific branch using Propel 1.6 Nested Set under Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, nested, branch, propel, children

I have nested set table like this (partially shown):

- ROOT

  - Boats
  - ATV

    - Sport
    - Utility
    - Youth
  - Motorcycle
  - Outboard Motors
  - Side x Side
  - Snowmobiles
  - WaveRunners
  - Generator

I have Propel working under Symfony2 but I can not figure out how using the Propel Bridge and the the Propel generated Modal how to get the children of a specific branch.

I have tried many combinations of different commands and queries with little results.

```
$rootNode = ProductLineQuery::create()->findRoot();
$children = $rootNode->getBranch(array('name' => 'ATV'));
```

Desired result should be that $children contains an array of ProductLine objects as follows:

- Sport
- Utility
- Youth

As these three fall under the "ATV" branch under the "ROOT" in my table example above.